# React image crop: How to set image to full screen?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, crop

I am trying to set an image that is displayed by the ReactCrop component to full screen (size of the window). The image is full size on some screens (Galaxy S5 emulator) but doesn't work on others (Iphone emulator). I am able to set the image to full screen when it's not in the ReactCrop component, but it doesn't work with React Crop. This is my code:

```
<ReactCrop
  src={src}
  style={{width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "absolute", left: "50%", marginLeft: "-50%", objectFit: "cover", objectPosition: "center"}}
  crop={crop}
  onImageLoaded={this.onImageLoaded}
  onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
  onChange={this.onCropChange}
/>
```

Here is a sandbox of my project:  https://codesandbox.io/s/8to8e?file=/src/App.js
How could I set the image to full screen?